# JSON error I can't fix?? (Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined')

Tags: json

I am getting the following error and I have no idea how to fix it:

> Blockquote
>   Error: Parse error on line 1660:
>   ...,            "Description": "Consultant psychiat
>   ----------------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Here's the portion of the file that is throwing this error:

```
{
        "ItemNum": "289",
        "ItemStartDate": "01.07.2008",
        "Category": "1",
        "Group": "A8",
        "ItemType": "S",
        "FeeType": "N",
        "NewItem": "N",
        "ItemChange": "N",
        "AnaesChange": "N",
        "DescriptorChange": "N",
        "FeeChange": "N",
        "EMSNChange": "N",
        "EMSNCap": "P",
        "BenefitType": "C",
        "BenefitStartDate": "01.07.2008",
        "FeeStartDate": "01.11.2012",
        "ScheduleFee": "263.90",
        "Benefit75": "197.95",
        "Benefit85": "224.35",
        "EMSNStartDate": "01.11.2012",
        "EMSNMaximumCap": "500.00",
        "EMSNPercentageCap": "300.00",
        "DescriptionStartDate": "01.11.2011",
        "Description": "consultant psychiatrist, referred consultation for assessment, diagnosis and development of a treatment and management plan for autism or any other pervasive developmental disorder - surgery or hospital professional attendance of at least 45 minutes duration, at consulting rooms or hospital, by a consultant physician in his or her specialty of psychiatry, for assessment, diagnosis and the preparation of a treatment and management plan for a child aged under 13 years, with autism or any other pervasive developmental disorder, who has been referred to the consultant psychiatrist by a referring practitioner, if the consultant psychiatrist does the following:(a) undertakes a comprehensive assessment of the child and forms a diagnosis (using the assistance of one or more  allied health providers where appropriate)(b) develops a treatment and management plan which must include the following: (i) the outcomes of the assessment; (ii) the diagnosis or diagnoses; (iii) opinion on risk assessment; (iv) treatment options and decisions; (v) appropriate medication recommendations, where necessary.(c) provides a copy of the treatment and management plan to the: (i) referring practitioner; and (ii) relevant allied health providers (where appropriate).not being an attendance on a child in respect of whom payment has previously been made under this item or items 135, 137 or 139."
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the error must be in a different part of the file, as it indicates the presence of the word `undefined` (unquoted), probably a value given to `DescriptionStartDate` somewhere. Try to locate that... `undefined` is not allowed as a value in JSON, however `null` is, so maybe replace that.

Comment: I got this error because I was creating json from SQL Server and then copying it and pasting into a json formatter. Problem was that SSMSC truncates the json leaving a trailing comma.

Answer (score 4):

This error causes because of quotes we have used in our JSON. Maybe somewhere you have used “ instead of " in your JSON. For resolving this error you have to replace all “ quotes with ".Please find validation checking result of your JSON as follow[image]

Comment: Please share code instead of images where possible.

Comment: @ArnavThorat it was just quote issue. I have used same json which is shared in question above and it was not validating due to quote issue ,so I have not shared the json again

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

remove the , at the end use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
to verify it works

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "ItemNum": "289",
    "ItemStartDate": "01.07.2008",
    "Category": "1",
    "Group": "A8",
    "ItemType": "S",
    "FeeType": "N",
    "NewItem": "N",
    "ItemChange": "N",
    "AnaesChange": "N",
    "DescriptorChange": "N",
    "FeeChange": "N",
    "EMSNChange": "N",
    "EMSNCap": "P",
    "BenefitType": "C",
    "BenefitStartDate": "01.07.2008",
    "FeeStartDate": "01.11.2012",
    "ScheduleFee": "263.90",
    "Benefit75": "197.95",
    "Benefit85": "224.35",
    "EMSNStartDate": "01.11.2012",
    "EMSNMaximumCap": "500.00",
    "EMSNPercentageCap": "300.00",
    "DescriptionStartDate": "01.11.2011",
    "Description": "consultant psychiatrist, referred consultation for assessment, diagnosis and development of a treatment and management plan for autism or any other pervasive developmental disorder - surgery or hospital professional attendance of at least 45 minutes duration, at consulting rooms or hospital, by a consultant physician in his or her specialty of psychiatry, for assessment, diagnosis and the preparation of a treatment and management plan for a child aged under 13 years, with autism or any other pervasive developmental disorder, who has been referred to the consultant psychiatrist by a referring practitioner, if the consultant psychiatrist does the following:(a) undertakes a comprehensive assessment of the child and forms a diagnosis (using the assistance of one or more  allied health providers where appropriate)(b) develops a treatment and management plan which must include the following: (i) the outcomes of the assessment; (ii) the diagnosis or diagnoses; (iii) opinion on risk assessment; (iv) treatment options and decisions; (v) appropriate medication recommendations, where necessary.(c) provides a copy of the treatment and management plan to the: (i) referring practitioner; and (ii) relevant allied health providers (where appropriate).not being an attendance on a child in respect of whom payment has previously been made under this item or items 135, 137 or 139."
}
```

Results:

Will compile as Valid JSON

Remove your comma , at the end

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem. Now if you run composer -vvv update
you get

```
Reading composer.json of git@bitbucket.org:test/test.git (master)
    Executing command (C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-test/test.git/): git show "72721b472adb50643e9bfd1745544db3522b58d2":"compoSkipped branch master, "72721b472adb50643e9bfd1745544db3522b58d2:composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
    Parse error on line 1:
    C:\Users\xxx\AppD
    ^
    Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

From verbose mode you can see that git is getting json from

```
 git show "72721b472adb50643e9bfd1745544db3522b58d2":"compoSkipped branch master, "72721b472adb50643e9bfd1745544db3522b58d2:composer.json"
```

The problem is in the console encoding from which you are running composer. In my case I have console encoding in CP-1250. When I change console encoding to ANSI it work without problem.