# VSCode Randomly popping this error up everywhere, not resolving until I reload the workspace

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

Everywhere something expects brackets, and a few other places, I have been finding this error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', "[", got ':(sometimes this : is different here)'
```

I have to reload my window to fix this every time, and I have no idea where this bug comes from. I've found it everywhere:

```css
/*CSS*/
:root{
~ /* This is where the error appears, where the tilde is.*/
    --bg-color:white;
    --popup-bg:whitesmoke;
}
```

```js
//Javascript
const interface = { ...
~ //Right here
```

It also appears in JSON, only when I edit it though. I first noticed it in my TSConfig.json files, and then it started popping up (almost)every time there's brackets.

Please help!

EDIT: This is my workspace:

build/index.js:

```js
var test = {
    error: false,
    name: "Someone",
    age: 10,
    appearance: {
        face: "red"
    }
};
```

./index.ts:

```
var test = {
    error:false,
    name:"Someone",
    age:10,
    appearance:{
        face:"red"
    }
}
```

./package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "apijs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

./tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": true,
        "outDir": "build/"
    }
    ~
}
~
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. New VSCode Workspace
2. Create index.ts as follows
3. Create tsconfig.json as follows
4. run `tsc`
5. Modify tsconfig.json.

After disabling all extensions the bug seems to have disappeared completely.

I individually tested ESLint and JSON extensions, with no luck. The bug is probably in one of my extensions.

Another edit: After re-enabling my extensions I removed the test typescript code and immediately got 2 errors in the same place at the beginning of my file.

Comment: I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435701/json-error-i-cant-fix-expecting-string-number-null-true-false) stackoverflow page, it is what I had, but it wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: show all the files you have in your workspace, or at least create a minimal workspace that has the error, just showing the error without the workspace content is useless, do you have the error if you disable all extensions

Comment: It's really impersistent for me. It only seems to happen when VSCode tries to deal with JS and JSON at the same time. It is super weird and I am trying to make it appear.

Comment: I made a new directory, I made a TSConfig that just sets `watch` to true and sets the `outDir` to `build/`. Then I ran `npm init -y`. Then I ran `git init`. Finally, I made an index.ts file and put in `{test:true}`. I messed around with it some and I got the error. After reloading the workspace, I could not find the same error at all. Then, I tried adding build options to the TSConfig. I immediately got this bug on the comma as well as the first four characters.

Comment: Also, once I remove the code causing the bug, the red line just moves to the beginning of  where the code I removed was. They pile up quick. I now have 8 errors in my TSConfig but I only see 2.

Comment: if you don't have a problem without extensions you have to find out which extension is the culprit. you can use `Help: Start Extension Bisect` to find the offender. If you have the error in the PROBLEMS panel you also have an indication who has generated the error (shown in a transparent text) Maybe change theme to default to see all text. Calling everything `test` makes it hard to determine what you remove if you remove `test`, also you could have unit tests.

Comment: I did that, it said markdown all in one was the culprit,  but even then, this bug is being so inconsistent that with it enabled, I am failing to get errors to confirm it. When it had disabled my CSS class intellisense is when I saw the bug actually happen, all the other times it was fine. I don't think that will be of much help.

Comment: Do I understand it correct: All Extensions disabled => no bugs, some extensions enabled => the bug, more extensions enabled => bug goes away? if so that is very strange

Comment: Yeah, that's what's happening. I have just been using ESLint and Eva theme to survive it.